# Computing the resultant force from xyz vectors in three.js

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js

I have a simulation with xyz angles and xyz G forces. All three G forces are drawn (scaled according to their value in floats) as arrays(vectors) from common 0,0,0 point.

Now i want to draw a resultant force from said point and from three said vectors.

Question is,how to do it in three.js? Or maybe someone has a nice example of that.

Comment: You can find a lot on vector calculating [on Google](https://www.google.se/webhp#q=sum+vectors+math). For example [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html) or [here](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors.html). Maybe this question is more something for **[math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)**

Comment: Maybe something for http://math.stackexchange.com